# Вывод переменной из JS (ajax) в index.html (в всплывающем окне)

Tags: форма

Форма отправки данных через ajax (2 файла)
**1.** mailform.js

```
    $("#sendMail").on("click", function () {

    var cityon = $("#cityon").val().trim();
    var cityin = $("#cityin").val().trim();
    var ves = $("#ves").val().trim();
    var name = $("#name").val().trim();
    var tel = $("#tel").val().trim();
    var email = $("#email").val().trim();
    var mass = $("#mass").val().trim();

    if (cityon == "") {
        $("#errormess").text("Введите данные А");
        return false;
    } else if (cityin == "") {
        $("#errormess").text("Введите данные Б");
        return false;
    } else if (ves == "") {
        $("#errormess").text("Введите данные С");
        return false;
    } else if (name == "") {
        $("#errormess").text("Введите Ваше Ф.И.О");
        return false;
    } else if (tel == "") {
        $("#errormess").text("Введите Ваш номер телефона");
        return false;
    }

    $("#errormess").text("");

    $('#openModal').css('display', 'block');
    $('#openModal').animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 500);

    
    $.ajax({
        url: '../themes/pup/ajax/mailform.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            'cityon': cityon,
            'cityin': cityin,
            'ves': ves,
            'name': name,
            'tel': tel,
            'email': email,
            'mass': mass
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#sendMail").prop("disabled", true);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data)
                alert("Вы допустили ошибки при заполнении данных");
            else
                $("#formrasgryz").trigger("reset");
            $("#sendMail").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });

});
```

**2.** Файл обработчик mailform.php

```
        <?php
    
    $recepient = "youmail@mail.ru";
    $siteName = "Имя сайта";
    
    $cityon = trim($_POST["cityon"]);
    $cityin = trim($_POST["cityin"]);
    $ves = trim($_POST["ves"]);
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $tel = trim($_POST["tel"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $mass = trim($_POST["mass"]);
    
    $message = "Первый: $cityon \nВторой: $cityin \nТретий: $ves \nИ.Ф.О: $name \nТелефон: $tel \nE-mail: $email \nПримечание / пожелания: $mass";
    
    $pagetitle = "Заявка с сайта \"$siteName\"";
    mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
    
    
    ?>
```

Как мне вывести переменные "var" из js (7 штук из формы) в всплывающее окно после заполнения формы и нажатия кнопки отправить? (Заполнил форму, нажал отправить, всплыло окно спс мол и там данные из JS которые заполнил юзер) + закрытие окна по клику на пустой области... Выручайте ребятЫ всю голову сломал. С уважением

---

```
var cityon = $("#cityon").val().trim();
document.getElementById('cityon').innerHTML = cityon;

<span id="cityon"></span>
```

*(не работает)*

Comment: Какие переменные? Ответ из php Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Мне нужно вывести значения заполненных полей не важно от куда из js или php файла

Answer (score 0):

```
let html = `<ul>
  <li>${cityon}<li>
</ul>`
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = html
```

И так со всеми переменными

Comment: Да, НОООО вывод происходит не во всплывающем окне а на белом фоне и с ul ом

Comment: Так я для примера сделал, а Вы можете найти по любому селектору Вашу модалку и вставить туда

Comment: Если не сложно для Очень не умных можно по подробнее с примером

Comment: document.querySelector('класс вашей модалки например').innerHTML = html
Если вы не знаете как найти элемент по селектору почитайте https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom

Comment: Ввожу id модального окна вместо body, реакции ни какой окно всплывает переменной не видно и не слышно

Comment: В консоль выведете вашу переменную с модалкой, может она undefined

Answer (score 0):

Модальное окно вывожу:

```
$('#openModal').css('display', 'block');
$('#openModal').animate({
    'opacity': 1
}, 500);
```

в html странице оно выглядит так:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modal">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <p class="modal-title">СПАСИБО ! Заявка отправлена</p>
                                        <a href="/" id="closeModal" title="Close" class="close">×</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
 <div>Переменная которая нужна что бы вывелась:
                                            <div id="cityon"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Содержимое модального окна...</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```